# Is there a way to get the node that a script tag is inside of?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to get the parent node that a script is inside of?

For example, if I have the following code, is there a way to get element, "BorderContainer1282" from within that block of code?

```
<div id="BorderContainer1282" >
    <input id="Button925" type="button" value="Button" >
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var isSame = this == document.getElementById('BorderContainer1282');
    document.getElementById('Button925').value = "Is this a reference to the parent node:" + isSame;
    </script>
</div >
```

**Update:**
It looks like I can check the last script block in the document.scripts array.

```
// returns BorderContainer1282
document.scripts[document.scripts.length-1].parentNode.id;
```

Not extensively tested. Seems to work in an older version of WebKit.

Comment: [`document.currentScript.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/document/currentScript), but there probably is a better way to do this.

Comment: `document.currentScript` appears to be undefined in my tests